# How can I make my NSIS silent installer block until complete?

Tags: nsis, silent-installer

When I run a silent NSIS installer (from the console, as in `installer.exe /S /D=C:\Foo`) it immediately moves to the background.  I'd like to wait until it has finished installing before I do anything else.  Is there a flag I can pass to tell the installer to be blocking?

Comment: How are you calling your installer? From a console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say anything about how you start the process in your question! NSIS installers are always "blocking", for a silent installer this means you just have to wait for the child process to end.

If the parent process is also a NSIS installer you can do `ExecWait '"c:\path\to\installer.exe" /S /D=C:\Foo'` or if it is a batch file you must use `start "" /WAIT "c:\path\to\installer.exe" /S /D=C:\Foo`

Comment: I clarified my question, and the start trick certainly works.  Why is it that that is needed with a silent nsis installer and not, for instance, silent MSI installs?

Comment: The console generally only waits for console programs, NSIS is a GUI application even in silent mode. Try running calc or other GUI applications and see what happens...